# How do I connect to a SQL-server table from C# and retrieve information in microsoft visual studio?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I need to use C# in Microsoft Visual Studio to connect to a specific table in a database in SQL Server, then retrieve the data and alter it in C#. I would like to use `System.Data.Sql` and class `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` rather than `SqlConnection`.

I've tried to use several example codes on stackoverflow to do this, but they aren't working because I don't know where to insert my specific information (the name of the server, database and table). If the server name is A, the database name is B and the table name is C, how do I use this code to retrieve my data?

```
using System.Data.Sql; 
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
        System.Data.DataTable table = instance.GetDataSources();
        DisplayData(table);
    }

    private static void DisplayData(System.Data.DataTable table)
    { 
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", col.ColumnName, row[col]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("=============");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SqlDataSourceEnumerator is for listing servers/instances - if you know the address already you are heading up the wrong path.  Use SqlConnection.

Comment: so to get a specific table I need to use a different command?

Comment: You use SqlConnection to connect to server A specifying database B then you can query table C.

Comment: Type “ADO.NET tutorial” into your favorite search page.

Answer (score 1):

Put your query in an [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) then create an [SqlDataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) using that command and use the [Fill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.fill(v=vs.110).aspx) method to populate your [DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx).

See [Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter)